# Что означает "сдвиг элементов массива вправо с позиции k до позиции t"?

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, функции

> Дан одномерный массив действительных чисел u размера n. Составив функцию, выполняющую сдвиг элементов массива вправо с позиции k до позиции t, выполнить сортировку вектора u по возрастанию методом вставки.

Не совсем понятно что означает "сдвиг элементов массива вправо с позиции k до позиции t". Всё ли здесь верно?

```
void shift(double* u, int n, int k, int t)
{
    double tmp = 0;
    if(t == n)
        t--;

    for(int i = k; i <= t; i++)
    {
        tmp = u[(i + (t-k)) % n];
        u[(i + (t-k)) % n] = u[i];
        u[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас получился сдвиг влево

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из стандартной реализации сортировки вставками, под

> сдвигом элементов массива вправо с позиции k до позиции t

подразумевается сдвинуть элементы с `k` до `t` на 1 позицию вправо, а `k`-ый элемент заменить на тот, который изначально находился на `t+1` позиции.

Например, массив `[1,2,3,4,5]` после сдвига элементов с 1 по 3 будет выглядеть следующим образом: `[1,5,2,3,4]`.

Функция для сдвига элементов:

```cpp
void shift(double u[], int n, int k, int t){
    //запоминаем элемент на t+1 позиции
    double temp = u[t+1];
    //сдвигаем весь отрезок на 1 вправо
    for(int i = t; i >= k; i--){
        u[i+1] = u[i];
    }
    //в начало отрезка записываем запомненный элемент
    u[k] = temp;
}
```

Сортировка вставками:

```cpp
void insertion_sort(double u[], int n){
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        //если нужно сдвинуть элементы
        if(u[i] < u[i-1]){
            int j;
            //поиск позиции, с которой будет происходить сдвиг
            for(j = i-1; j >= 0; j--){
                if(u[j] < u[i]){
                    break;
                }
            }
            shift(u, n, j+1, i-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё работает!